# Revit MEP 2011 C# iterate through all equipment

Tags: c#, revit-api

I want to iterate through all the equipment in a drawing and get the name of the equipment.

Here is what I have:

```
UIApplication uiapp = commandData.Application;
UIDocument uidoc = uiapp.ActiveUIDocument;
Application app = uiapp.Application;
Document doc = uidoc.Document;

// get all PanelScheduleView instances in the Revit document.
FilteredElementCollector fec = new FilteredElementCollector(doc);
ElementClassFilter EquipmentViewsAreWanted = 
  new ElementClassFilter(typeof(ElectricalEquipment));
fec.WherePasses(EquipmentViewsAreWanted);
List<Element> eViews = fec.ToElements() as List<Element>;

StringBuilder Disp = new StringBuilder();

foreach (ElectricalEquipment element in eViews)
{
    Disp.Append("\n" + element.);
}

System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(Disp.ToString());
```

I get the following error at the `foreach` loop:

> Cannot convert type 'Autodesk.Revit.DB.Element' to
>   'Autodesk.Revit.DB.Electrical.ElectricalEquipment'

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eViews is a list of `Element` whereas you're trying iterate over them as though they're `ElectricalEquipment`.  Unless `Element` inherits from `ElectricalEquipment` or has an explicit cast operator, you won't be able to do this.

If you change your for loop to:

```
foreach(Element element in eViews)
{
    Disp.Append("\n" + element);
}
```

It will compile, however it might not produce the required outcome.

Comment: Not exactly the answer, but it brought me to what I was looking for. Basically, you can make the Electrical equipment into an array with fec.toArray() instead of toElements; then iterate. Thanks for the help.